# sql delete error in oracle as 'ORA-00933: Sql command not properly ended'

Tags: oracle

The sql block works fine:

```
select * from aciktan_atama_tercihler LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MIN(t.eklenme_tarihi) as row_id,
                                                              t.tcno,
                                                              t.hastane_kodu,
                                                              t.tercih_sira
                                                         FROM aciktan_atama_tercihler t
                                                        where t.silindi = '0'
                                                        GROUP BY tcno,
                                                                 hastane_kodu,
                                                                 tercih_sira) KeepRows ON aciktan_atama_tercihler.eklenme_tarihi = KeepRows.row_id
 WHERE KeepRows.row_id IS NULL
   and aciktan_atama_tercihler.silindi = '0'
```

but, if I change it to delete like below, it gives error as 'ORA-00933: Sql command not properly ended', how can I solve this? :

```
delete from aciktan_atama_tercihler LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MIN(t.eklenme_tarihi) as row_id,
                                                              t.tcno,
                                                              t.hastane_kodu,
                                                              t.tercih_sira
                                                         FROM aciktan_atama_tercihler t
                                                        where t.silindi = '0'
                                                        GROUP BY tcno,
                                                                 hastane_kodu,
                                                                 tercih_sira) KeepRows ON aciktan_atama_tercihler.eklenme_tarihi = KeepRows.row_id
 WHERE KeepRows.row_id IS NULL
   and aciktan_atama_tercihler.silindi = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete the records from the `aciktan_atama_tercihler` table:

```
DELETE FROM aciktan_atama_tercihler
 WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT aciktan_atama_tercihler.rowid
                   FROM aciktan_atama_tercihler  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MIN(t.eklenme_tarihi) as row_id,
                                t.tcno,
                                t.hastane_kodu,
                                t.tercih_sira
                           FROM aciktan_atama_tercihler t
                          WHERE t.silindi = '0'
                       GROUP BY tcno,
                                hastane_kodu,
                                tercih_sira) KeepRows ON aciktan_atama_tercihler.eklenme_tarihi = KeepRows.row_id
     WHERE KeepRows.row_id IS NULL
       and aciktan_atama_tercihler.silindi = '0')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it results in error => ORA-00904 : "ACIKTAN_ATAMA_TERCIHLER"."EKLENME_TARIHI" : invalid identifier

Comment: Could you comment the entire message?

Comment: ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24473/discussion-between-serefbilge-and-mt-schneiders)